# What is the syntax of a static function?

Tags: c, doxygen

I'm documenting code C with doxygen but this function can´t

```
/**
* @fn          void myApp_StartReporting( void )
*
* @brief       bla bla....
*
* @see     myAccReportPeriod
*
* @return      none
*/
static void myApp_StartReporting( void );
```

If remove static the documentation is ok.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Doesn't a `static` function have internal linkage?

Comment: what happens if you remove the line with @fn ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default doxygen skips static functions. Did you set the `EXTRACT_STATIC = YES` option in your Doxyfile?

Also a style note (which was my first guess on what's wrong):
If the documentation block is placed immediately before the entity that it describes the `@fn` tag is not needed.

Comment: Thank you very much Anders now all ok